# What is the most efficient strategy for lookups on a large, static table which is already in sorted order (sqlite)?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sorting, indexing

I have a basic reverse lookup table in which the ids are **already sorted in ascending numerical order**:

```
id INT NOT NULL,
value INT NOT NULL
```

The ids are **not unique**; each id has from 5 to 25,000 associated values. Each id is independent, i.e., no relationships between the ids.

The table is static. Read only, no inserts or updates ever. The table has 100-200 million records. The database itself will be around 7-12gb. Sqlite.

I will do frequent lookups in this table and want the fastest response time for each query. Lookups are one-direction only, unordered, and always of the form:

```
SELECT value WHERE id IN (x,y,z)
```

What advantages does the pre-sorted order give me in terms of database efficiency? What should I do differently than I would with typical unordered tables? How do I tell sql that it's an ordered list?

What about indices: is it necessary or even helpful to create an index on id?

[**Updated** for clustered comment thanks to Gordon Linoff]. As far as I can tell, sqlite doesn't support clustered indices directly. The [wiki](https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=PerformanceTuning) says: "Are [clustered indices] supported? No, but if you use INTEGER PRIMARY KEY it acts as a clustered index." In my situation, the column id is not unique...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that space is not an issue, you should create an index on `(id, value)`.  This should be sufficient for your purposes.

However, if the table is static, then I would recommend that you create a *clustered* index when you create the table.  The index would have the same keys, `(id, value)`.

Comment: I couldn't find much about sqlite and clustered indices. All I saw was this mention on the sqlite wiki (https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=PerformanceTuning): "Are [clustered indices] supported? No, but if you use INTEGER PRIMARY KEY it acts as a clustered index."

Comment: @LunaiThi . . . Oops, I missed that.  Well, a regular index should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the table happens to be sorted, the database does not know about this, so you'd still need an index.

It is a better idea to use a [WITHOUT ROWID table](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) (what other DBs call a clustered index):

```
CREATE TABLE MyLittleLookupTable (
    id    INTEGER,
    value INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, value)
) WITHOUT ROWID;
```

Comment: From sqlite.org: "WITHOUT ROWID tables will work correctly (that is to say, they provide the correct answer) for tables with a single INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. However, ordinary rowid tables will run faster in that case. Hence, it is good design to avoid creating WITHOUT ROWID tables with single-column PRIMARY KEYs of type INTEGER"...So, is a composite KEY (id, value) better than single-column KEY (id)? It just does 1 lookup in 1 table (the index) rather than 2 lookups. If composite key is better, does composite with WITHOUT ROWID work better? In tests, it doesn't make much difference with my data.

Comment: Your table does not have a single-column primary key (because `id` is not unique), so it does not make sense to ask whether it would be better. A separate index would require more storage.